# SCORM: Web based SCORM player in Java

Tags: java, spring, jsp, scorm, scorm2004

I'am looking for a free SCORM player which can be integrated into java Website.I also need help on its integration part.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your effort. and show code what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Rembo: I did't start.Now I'am learning about SCORM since I'am new in SCORM. Please suggest me the SCORM player which can be integrated easily.

Answer (score 1):

We help people add SCORM players to their applications, all the time.  I'm not aware of a free integratable option.  However, some open-source tools, such as Moodle, can provide a SCORM 1.2 player for you.

If you are willing to license some software, our SCORM Cloud and SCORM Engine solutions are designed to provide a player for SCORM 1.1, SCORM 1.2, SCORM 2004 (2nd, 3rd, & 4th editions), AICC, PENS, and Tin Can API.  All our solutions are compatible with the Java environment.

The SCORM Cloud provides a free testing sandbox, with a debug log, so you can see the two way communication between a course and a SCORM player.  If you need some example courses, to help you get started and to benchmark with, we offer a free library of SCORM courses (in every version and style) [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/).

If you want to build your own player ADL's official specification documentation, [found here](http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/), is the best place to begin.  I recommend starting with SCORM 1.2, as it is the most widely-used version of the standard.

If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask.  We're always happy to help, ask us anything... really. (info@scorm.com)